# vector searching rhyming words

Tags: c++, search, vector

In my program I have to prompt the user for a word, and report all words that rhyme (by checking if the last 3 letters are the same}.
For example if the word "time" was entered by the user I have to return lime, dime, intime, regime, etc. form a vector which has 106 thousand words.

All 106 thousand words are in a vector `vector<string>words` the vector would contain

```
time, lime, line, dime, intime, abaca, clilica, dog, ball, regime, sentence, return, which, contain, word, pool, etc....
```

Out of all of this I need to get the words that rhythm with the word that the user has entered.

How do I create a function to find all of this with a string input which the user enters?

Comment: To create a function you'll need to write its code, and then check that it compiles and produces correct results for your inputs.

Comment: It seems like whoever gave you this task has no idea about what rhyming is. "intime" (which has a French pronunciation) and "regime" (which sounds like "team") *don't* rhyme with "time". But "time" *does* rhyme with "rhyme".

Comment: if you have C++20, `std::string::ends_with`

Comment: Sort the vector on the last three characters of the strings first.

Comment: please show your attempt. This is a basic exercise, giving you the solution would spoil the exercise for you. Do you know how to get last 3 chars of a string? Do you know how to compare two strings? We cannot know where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You say `rhyme` = `the last 3 letters are the same`.  106 thousand words in vector means you've got sufficient memory so suggesting the below method to trade off space for time.

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string>> rhymesMap;
int const rhymesSuffixLength = 3;

void preProcess(vector<string>& words){
    for(auto const& word: words){
        if(word.size() < rhymesSuffixLength)
            continue;
        string suffix = word.substr(word.size() - rhymesSuffixLength);
        rhymesMap[suffix].push_back(word);
    }
}

vector<string> getRhymes(string word){
    if(word.size() < rhymesSuffixLength)
        return {};
    string suffix = word.substr(word.size() - rhymesSuffixLength);
    return rhymesMap[suffix];
}
```

To search from `vector` for rhymes is too slow, `unordered_map` will require a lookup and pretty fast.

Comment: You should pass those function arguments by reference. The for loop should also use `auto&&` or `auto const&`. Otherwise they will be copied each time.

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot that in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with English words the alphabet is 26 characters large. So there are only 17576 = 26<sup>3</sup> buckets. That means one can afford constant time lookup using a container with contiguous memory.

```
template <auto N, unsigned E>
inline constexpr auto power = N*power<N,E-1>;
template <auto N>
inline constexpr auto power<N,0> = decltype(N)(1);

template <unsigned suffix_len = 3, unsigned alphabet = 'z'-'a'+1>
class Rhyme {
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> table; // <----

    static unsigned serialise(std::string const& s) {
      unsigned result = 0;
      if (s.size() >= 3) {
        result += 1;
        for (auto it = std::next(std::begin(s),s.size()-3); it != std::end(s); ++it) {
          result *= alphabet;
          result += *it-'a';
        }
      }
      return result;
    }   
  public:
    Rhyme(std::vector<std::string> const& dictionary) : table{} {
      table.resize(power<alphabet,suffix_len>+1);
      for (auto const& s: dictionary) {
        if (auto index = serialise(s)) {
          table[index].emplace_back(s);
        }
      }
    }   

    std::vector<std::string> const& lookup(std::string const& key) const {
      return table[serialise(key)];
    }   
};
```

This can be used fairly straightforward and has the bonus to preserve the input ordering.

```
std::vector<std::string> input =
  { "time", "lime", "line", "dime", "intime", "abaca", "clilica", "dog", "ball", "regime", "sentence", "return", "which", "contain", "word", "pool" };
Rhyme r(input);
for (auto const& s: r.lookup("slime")) {
  std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
time
lime
dime
intime
regime
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jYxzn3)